# How to fill matplotlib polygon regardless of point order?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I am trying to make the area shown below all green.

So far I use this:
But not the whole four-sided-figure is coloured.

```
x,y = [3.3333333333333335, 5.0, -0.0, -0.0], [3.333333333333333, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0]
my_plot.fill(x, y, "g")
```

It would be possible to fix the rotation of x and y in this specific example. But in other times it would not work.

Is there a way to fill everything between the area between given points, regardless of any order of the points?

[image: The problem]

## **SOLUTION:**

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
points = np.array(Utils2D.get_valid_intersections(lin_prog.constraints))
hull = ConvexHull(points)
my_plot.fill(points[hull.vertices, 0], points[hull.vertices, 1])
```

Comment: You could calculate the convex hull of the points, and then fill that polygon.

Comment: How do would I do that @JohanC? The points I have are already the convex hull, arent they? I mean my shape is convex.

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer and [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that all the original points already lie on the convex hull, you can order them via the angle their coordinates make versus their center:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.array([3.3333333333333335, 5.0, -0.0, -0.0]), np.array([3.333333333333333, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0])
order = np.argsort(np.arctan2(y - y.mean(), x - x.mean()))
plt.fill(x[order], y[order], "g", alpha=0.5)
```

[image: find and fill convex hull]